# How to write this cron expression?

Tags: cron, quartz.net, cronexpression

How to write cron expression (for [quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html), but that shouldn't matter) that would trigger:

> every week day from 8am to 7pm once in half an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested:

```
0 0/30 8-18 ? * 1-5
```

NOTE: Last trigger will fire at 18:30, not 19:00. If you change to:

```
0 0/30 8-19 ? * 1-5
```

Last trigger will be 19:30. I don't believe there is a way to have last trigger fire at exactly 19:00, with half-hourly intervals.